# random choice, specific distributions, variable applicability

Tags: algorithm, distribution, random

Imagine I have person 1, 2, 3 and 4, then I have shirt styles A, B, C, D and I want to distribute the shirt styles to the people such that 25% of them get style A, 25% get style B, 25% get style C and 25% get style D but some of the people refuse to wear certain styles, these people are represented by Fs. How can I randomly match all the people with the styles they are willing to wear to get the approximate distribution?

```
   A B C D
 1 T F T T
 2 T F F F 
 3 T T T T
 4 T T T F
```

In this case this is easy and 25% is can be fully achieved, just give each person a different style. However, I intend to take this problem beyond this simple situation, my solution has to be generic. The number or styles, the number of people, and the distribution is all variable. Sometimes, the distribution will be impossible to create 100% accurately, approximate/close/best effor is expected. The selection process should be random and attempt to maintain the distribution.

I'm pretty agnostic to the language here, I'm just seeking the algorithm. Though preferably it would be able to be distributed.

Answer (score 0):

Finding a solution when you are hampered by the Fs is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem. One way to select an arbitrary assignment when there are many would be to set random costs where a style is acceptable to a person and then let it find the assignment with lowest possible cost. However it is not obvious that this will fit any natural definition of random. One (very inefficient) natural definition of random would be to select from all possible assignments at random until you get one that is acceptable to everybody. The distribution you get from this might not be the same as the one you would get by setting up random costs and then solving the resulting assignment problem.

Comment: Looking at the assignment problem now, it is pretty close but the Fs are true complete refusals. If the example were about matching taxi drivers to customers, it isn't just that it costs more to get to a customer (b/c of distance), it is that it is physically impossible to get to the customer. And yeah, the inefficient problem would be quite bad in my scaled case hehe. True randomness is not required. Thought: could duplicate the styles to the right distribution, then assign people to styles, and perhaps make a couple passes and/or many swaps.

Comment: You can handle true complete refusals with the assignment problem as long as there is a large enough difference between costs. If the cost of T is 0 and the cost of F is 1 then if it is at all possible the assignment problem will find you a solution with a total cost of 0, using only Ts. If the minimum cost solution it finds is not cost 0, so that it uses some Fs, this means that there is no zero cost solution available using only Ts.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the term 'randomly match' which should be used with caution. The correct interpretation, I believe, is a random selection from the set of all valid solutions, so basically if we could enumerate all valid solution - we could trivially solve the problem.

You are looking for a close-enough solution, so we need to better define what a valid solution is. I suggest to define some threshold (say 1% error at most).

In your example, there are 4 groups (those assigned with shirt style A/B/C/D). Therefore, there are 2^4-1 possible person archetypes (love/hate each of A/B/C/D, with the assumption that anyone loves at least one shirt style). Each archetype population has a given population size, and each archetype can be assigned to some of the 4 groups (1 or more).

The goal is to divide the population of each archetype between the 4 groups, such that say, the size of each group is between L and H.

Lets formalize it.

**Problem statement:**

- Denote A(0001),...,A(1111): the population size of each of the 15 archetypes
- Denote G1(0001): the size of A(0001) assigned to G1, etc.

Given

- L,H: constants
- A(0001),...,A(1111): 15 constants

Our goal is to find all integer solutions for

G1(0001),G1(0011),G1(0101),G1(0111),G1(1001),G1(1011),G1(1101),G1(1111),
G2(0010),G2(0011),G2(0110),G2(0111),G2(1010),G2(1011),G2(1110),G2(1111),
G3(0100),G3(0101),G3(0110),G3(0111),G3(1100),G3(1101),G3(1110),G3(1111),
G4(1000),G4(1001),G4(1010),G4(1011),G4(1100),G4(1101),G4(1110),G4(1111)

subject to:

- G1(0001) = A(0001)
- G2(0010) = A(0010)
- G2(0011) + G1(0011) = A(0011)
- G3(0100) = A(0100)
- G3(0101) + G1(0101) = A(0101)
- G3(0110) + G2(0110) = A(0110)
- G3(0111) + G2(0101) + G1(0101) = A(0111)
- G4(1000) = A(1000)
- G4(1001) + G1(1001) = A(1001)
- G4(1010) + G2(1010) = A(1010)
- G4(1011) + G2(1011) + G1(1011) = A(1011)
- G4(1100) + G3(1100) = A(1100)
- G4(1101) + G3(1101) + G1(1101) = A(1101)
- G4(1110) + G3(1110) + G2(1110) = A(1110)
- G4(1111) + G3(1111) + G2(1111) + G1(1111) = A(1111)
- L < G1(0001)+G1(0011)+G1(0101)+G1(0111)+G1(1001)+G1(1011)+G1(1101)+G1(1111) < 
  H
- L < G2(0010)+G2(0011)+G2(0110)+G2(0111)+G2(1010)+G2(1011)+G2(1110)+G2(1111) < 
  H
- L < G3(0100)+G3(0101)+G3(0110)+G3(0111)+G3(1100)+G3(1101)+G3(1110)+G3(1111) < 
  H
- L < G4(1000)+G4(1001)+G4(1010)+G4(1011)+G4(1100)+G4(1101)+G4(1110)+G4(1111) < 
  H

Now we can use an integer programming solver for the job.